# Microsoft Excel Copy and Paste with Format of Date

Tags: excel, vba, date, copy, paste

Can anyone help me with copying and pasting but keep the format of the data to be date for all the dates and numbers for all the numbers. So for example I have Customer ID which should be 3 digits (000), and date to be in date format. But when I copy and paste, the date became an weird integer and the ID become 1 digit. Here is the output now

Copy from:

001       AVC     BDE     130     6/23/2013

When I paste it becomes:

Cust ID   Name    Type    Amount  Date
1     AVC     BDE     130     41448

Can anyone help?
Here is my code

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F1").Copy
wkbDisplayOrder.Worksheets("Customer's Order").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Can you add another line lik epaste:=xlPasteFormat again? I'm sorry I don't do much VBA.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your happy with the formatting that is in the copy fields then you can just do a simple paste instead of paste special.  Right now your code is only pasting values because of this line:

```
Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

You can also just change it to this instead:

```
Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code (UN - Tested)

```
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F1").Copy
    wkbDisplayOrder.Worksheets("Customer's Order").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
    ActiveSheet.Range("E1").NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```